# On Google Sheets Google Analytics Add on, how can I filter by page?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, regex

I am using the Google Analytics Add on in Google Sheets.

I need to add a filter that enables my report to only show URLs containing the word "blog"

The blog pages are not in a directory, e.g. `example.com/blog/url.thmkl`, as if they were I could just use the following filter: `ga:pagePath=~^/blog/$`

My problem is that the word blog only appears in all of the URLs.

Is there a filter I can set up to only show pages that contain the word 'blog' in the page URL (but doesn't require them to be in a directory called blog)?